# Azure ignores site config settings in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to develop an ARM template for deployment of multiple webapps, but I am stuck trying to configure the webapp using the settings available in Microsoft.Web/sites/config. Whatever I put in there, the settings are just ignored when I deploy the webapp. I'm basing my template on [David Ebbos example](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/ARMTemplates/WebAppManyFeatures.json).

This is what I am trying at the moment:

```
// Serverfarm (appservice)
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
    "sku": {
        "name": "B1",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "size": "B1",
        "family": "B",
        "capacity": 1
    },
    "name": "[variables('appSvcName')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "tags": {
        "project": "[[variables('webAppName')]]"
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('appSvcName')]",
        "numberOfWorkers": 1
    }
},
// Site (Webapp)
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "tags": {
        "project": "[[variables('webAppName')]]"
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appSvcName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appSvcName'))]",
        "hostNames": [
            "[concat(variables('webAppName'), '.azurewebsites.net')]"
        ],
        "enabledHostNames": [
            "[concat(variables('webAppName'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "[concat(variables('webAppName'), '.scm.azurewebsites.net')]"
        ],
        // TODO : These resources are ignored so far
        "resources": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                "name": "web",
                "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
                "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webAppName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "phpVersion": "",
                    "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.6",
                    "use32BitWorkerProcess": false, /* 64-bit platform */
                    "webSocketsEnabled": true,
                    "alwaysOn": true,
                    "requestTracingEnabled": true, /* Failed request tracing, aka 'freb' */
                    "httpLoggingEnabled": true, /* IIS logs (aka Web server logging) */
                    "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 40, /* 40 MB limit for IIS logs */
                    "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": true, /* Detailed error messages  */
                    "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
                    "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2015",
                    "defaultDocuments": [
                        "default.aspx",
                        "Default.htm",
                        "Default.html",
                        "index.html",
                        "hostingstart.html"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                "name": "connectionstrings",
                "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
                "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webAppName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "umbracoDbDsn": {
                        "value": "[concat('Data Source=tcp:', reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerName'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName, ',1433;Initial Catalog=', variables('sqlDbName'), ';User Id=', variables('appSvcName'), '@', variables('sqlServerName'), ';Password=e15cO1PtIR5dtq3zUlwK;')]",
                        "type": "SQLAzure"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

One thing I am a bit confused about is that when I run `(Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web).ResourceTypes` in my azure powershell console there is no sites/config ResourceTypeName available.

What gives? Have the config resourcetype been removed from the template definitions? Am I using the wrong apiVersion? I have tried a number of different combinations, to no avail.

Comment: Why do you put "resources" inside "properties"? It should be outside of "properties" and under your web app.

Comment: I hadn't noticed @JackZeng thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this blog - 
http://wp.sjkp.dk/arm-templates-set-always-on-and-other-site-properties/

You would need siteConfig object under resource.properties of web/config.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "Website"
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "web",
            "type": "config",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('webSiteName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "javaVersion": "1.8",
                "javaContainer": "TOMCAT",
                "javaContainerVersion": "8.0",
                "siteConfig": {
                    "<supported-property>": "<value>",
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors in the schema, as commented by @JackZheng. These errors wasn't reported by the `Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` command either, making it somewhat harder to find and correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use APP settings under resources->properties ->SiteConfig as shown below

```
 "siteConfig": {
            "appSettings": [
                {
                    "name": "AppSetting1",
                    "value": "Value1"
                }
            ]
        }
```