# Azure: Powershell: Set-AzureRmWebApp: How to set the "alwaysOn" property

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

I am running Powershell 5 and trying to manipulate my Azure WebApp object using **Set-AzureRmWebApp** (and NOT  Set-AzureResource) to set the "Always On" property of the web app.

My basic code snippet starts with a running web app named **"myWebApp"**, and looks like this:

```
$name = "myWebApp"
$resourceGroupName = "myResourceGroup"
$app_settings = @{"WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES"="*";"CommonDatabase"="Common";"WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION"="0.10.32"}

$result1 = Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AppSettings $app_settings -Name $name
$result2 = Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName  -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $this.name -PropertyObject $propertiesObject -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

The first **Set-AzureRmWebApp** statement works. It sets all the variables in **$app_settings**, and they become visible in the Azure Portal blade for **myWebApp**.

I tried using **"Always On"= on** as a property in **$app_settings** with Set-AzureRmWebApp, and it appeared in the App Settings sub-list in the properties of "myWebApp" on the Azure portal blade, but the actual property "Always On" in the general settings remained off.

I read on another site that using **Set-AzureRmResource** would work, so I tried it, but it failed.

What do I need to do in Powershell to set a property in the General Settings of my Azure WebApp, specifically **"Always On"**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to enable Always On for Azure websites through management/resource management APIs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756644/is-it-possible-to-enable-always-on-for-azure-websites-through-management-resourc)

Comment: Look there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36811987/1275334

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**"Always On"** is not supported if WebApp is in a free Service Plan tier. If the WebApp is in a free tier, please scale up the App Service Plan. Please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview#scale-an-app-service-plan) for more info about how to scale up the App Service Plan.Please have a try to use the solution that sharbag mentioned. It is worked for me and I also check the run result from the azure portal. Snipped code from the solution is as followings:

```
   $ResourceGroupName = 'Your Group Name'

   $WebAppName = 'Your WebApp Name'

   $WebAppPropertiesObject = @{"siteConfig" = @{"AlwaysOn" = $true}}

    $WebAppResourceType = 'microsoft.web/sites'

    $webAppResource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType $WebAppResourceType -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $WebAppName

    $webAppResource | Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $WebAppPropertiesObject -Force
```

[image]

If the WebApp in a free tier service plan, when we try to run the PowerShell command to enable **"Always On"** then we will get the following error message.

[image]

Comment: I am on a paid plan. It is just formatting that properties hash which doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: Using `Set-AzWebApp` in v 4.2.0, I was getting `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AlwaysOn'`. Changing `Get-AzureRmResource` to `Get-AzResource`, this answer worked for me.