# How do I change 'always-on' for an Azure Function App using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm using a 'Basic' plan. I want to create a script which can switch 'always-on' to false, then change the service plan to the free tier. When I need the function again I can reverse the settings. Why am I doing this? So I can ensure the App service plan keeps the same outbound IP addresses. I don't want to be paying for a Basic plan all the time so a simple script to do this is required.

I am using the latest 'AZ' modules.

```
$site = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name  $SiteName
$site.SiteConfig.AlwaysOn = $false

Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $SiteName ???
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Setting App Service Plan**

```
Set-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName "myrgname"  -Name "my app service plan name" -Tier Basic -WorkerSize Small
```

For Free, you can change the Tier name to `Free`

**Setting Always On**

```
Connect-AzAccount

$webApp = Get-AzResource -ResourceType 'microsoft.web/sites' -ResourceGroupName 'myrgname' -ResourceName 'my function app name'

$webApp | Set-AzResource -PropertyObject @{"siteConfig" = @{"AlwaysOn" = $false}}
```

Here are two other similar SO posts.. difference is they don't tackle App Service Plan tier changes or make use of the latest `Az` modules [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756644/is-it-possible-to-enable-always-on-for-azure-websites-through-management-resourc/36811987#36811987) and [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40794622/azure-powershell-set-azurermwebapp-how-to-set-the-alwayson-property)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pipe the modified application to `Set-AzWebApp`.

```
$app = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $ApplicationName
$app.SiteConfig.AlwaysOn = $false
$app | Set-AzWebApp
```